# What is the shortest way to pretty print a org.w3c.dom.Document to stdout?

Tags: java, xml, dom, w3c

What is the easiest way to pretty print (a.k.a. formatted) a `org.w3c.dom.Document` to stdout?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Call `printDocument(doc, System.out)`, where that method looks like this:

```
public static void printDocument(Document doc, OutputStream out) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), 
         new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")));
}
```

(The `indent-amount` is optional, and might not work with your particular configuration)

Comment: Isn't it ironic that that's the "easiest" way to simply print an XML document in Java?

Comment: on the other hand you have plenty of control ;)

Comment: Brilliant! And yes, it is a bit much text but it is crystal clear what the selected options are and Eclipse/Netbeans really help you write this. Show me a smaller version and I tell you what it cannot do. Worse, I will tell you where you need 3 debugging rounds to get it right ...

Comment: I swear to god Java.. make me write ridiculous number of lines of code for something that can be done in one or two in other languages... with full control too..

Comment: But if your XML contains astral characters, and you are using Xalan, note https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2419 and see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11987283/1031689

Comment: If you are seeing unexpected newlines in the output, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33541820/415404

Answer (score 12):

How about:

```java
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc);
format.setIndenting(true);
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(System.out, format);
serializer.serialize(doc);
```

Comment: While easier, this approach requires Xerces

Comment: I can add that today XMLSerializer and OutputFormat are deprecated

Answer (score 10):

Try [jcabi-xml](http://xml.jcabi.com) with one liner:

```
String xml = new XMLDocument(document).toString();
```

This is the dependency you need:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcabi-xml</artifactId>
  <version>0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private void printNode(Node rootNode, String spacer) {
    System.out.println(spacer + rootNode.getNodeName() + " -> " + rootNode.getNodeValue());
    NodeList nl = rootNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
        printNode(nl.item(i), spacer + "   ");
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that the Q asks for the shortest, but (for the benefit of anyone else) perhaps you could elaborate your answer to explain what's going on?

Comment: html -> 
    head -> 
       meta -> 
       title -> 
    body -> 

If I place a space of string as the spacer above is the result is what I get. Is it what its intended to do? A full print of the XML is what is needed I think when it meants pretty printed.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a nicely formated output by using recursive descent/ascent.

```
private static boolean skipNL;
private static String printXML(Node rootNode) {
    String tab = "";
    skipNL = false;
    return(printXML(rootNode, tab));
}
private static String printXML(Node rootNode, String tab) {
    String print = "";
    if(rootNode.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        print += "\n"+tab+"<"+rootNode.getNodeName()+">";
    }
    NodeList nl = rootNode.getChildNodes();
    if(nl.getLength()>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            print += printXML(nl.item(i), tab+"  ");    // \t
        }
    } else {
        if(rootNode.getNodeValue()!=null) {
            print = rootNode.getNodeValue();
        }
        skipNL = true;
    }
    if(rootNode.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        if(!skipNL) {
            print += "\n"+tab;
        }
        skipNL = false;
        print += "</"+rootNode.getNodeName()+">";
    }
    return(print);
}
```

Comment: This is very incomplete.

Answer (score -2):

if you use dom4j, it would be dom4JDOM.asString()