# Print org.w3c.dom.Document on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm sending from spring controller ModelAndView with object org.w3c.dom.Document. So I need to print it on my jsp without scriplets. Is there any way to do this with jstl?
ThanX))

Answer (score 2):

JSTL has [XML tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/x/tld-summary.html). You can try `<x:out>`

But it might be better to use a Controller (or Servlet) and print the document to the `response.getOutputStream()`, using the method I provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325388/java-shortest-way-to-pretty-print-to-stdout-a-org-w3c-dom-document/2325407#2325407)