# splitting one line string into multiple lines

Tags: java, string

i have a string in single line

```
String s = "<Item><productname>COOLER MASTER Hyper 212 EVO RR-212E-20PK-R2
</productname><Price>$33.99</Price><ItemID>1000</ItemID></Item>";
```

inside the above string  , after the ">" new line should started and required output should like

```
<Item>
 <productname>COOLER MASTER Hyper 212 EVO RR-212E-20PK-R2 </productname>
 <Price>$33.99</Price> 
 <ItemID>1000</ItemID>
</Item>
```

Comment: better yet http://stackoverflow.com/a/2325407/169277, you need not use regex

Comment: -1 for not showing any effort of your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to parse the XML, and use the [OutputKeys.INDENT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html) option of the [Transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) class to output the XML formatted.

The following example

```
Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(s));

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 4);

Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
transformer.transform(source, result);

String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();
System.out.println(xmlOutput);

String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();
System.out.println(xmlOutput);
```

produces the output below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
    <productname>COOLER MASTER Hyper 212 EVO RR-212E-20PK-R2</productname>
    <Price>$33.99</Price>
    <ItemID>1000</ItemID>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String newString = s.replaceAll("><", ">\n <");
```

cheers

Comment: Won't work as opening and closing tags will be on a separate lines

Comment: Why use replaceAll? You're not using regex, so just use replace()

Answer (score 1):

you're probably best off with a pretty printer here, since that's what you're really trying to do.  W3C, Xerces, JDOM, etc... all have output capability that allows you to read in xml, and spit it out pretty printed.

Here's a JDOM Example:

```
String input = "...";
Document document = new SAXBuilder().build(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));
ByteArrayOutputStream pretty = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
outputter.output(document, pretty);
System.out.println(pretty.toString());
```

This site has some good examples of how to do it in other ways:

http://www.chipkillmar.net/2009/03/25/pretty-print-xml-from-a-dom/