# Serializing supplementary unicode characters into XML documents with Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, unicode, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize DOM documents with supplementary unicode characters such as U+1D49C (𝒜, mathematical script capital A). Creating a node with such a character is not a problem (I just set the node value to the UTF-16 equivalent, "\uD835\uDC9C"). When serializing, however, Xalan and XSLTC (with a Transformer) and Xerces (with LSSerializer) all create invalid character entities like "&#55349;&#56476;" instead of "&#119964;". I tried the "normalize-characters" parameter for LSSerializer, but it is not supported. Only Saxon gets it right, without using a character entity when the encoding is unicode.

I cannot use Saxon in practice (among other reasons, I use Java applets and do not want to load another jar), so I am looking for a solution with the default JDK libraries. Is it possible to get valid XML documents serialized from a DOM document with supplementary unicode characters ?

[edit] I found someone else who encountered this problem : http://www.dragishak.com/?p=131

[edit2] actually, it seems to work with LSSerializer when I don't have xerces on the classpath (the class used is com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl). It does not work with a transformer and com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.

Comment: Are you processing both ends? If so, is there a reason you can't just encode it yourself (base64, urlencode, etc) on the serializing side and then on the deserializing side reverse the process?

Comment: I could do that, but I'm looking for an easier solution.

Comment: This looks like a definite bug in the serializers.  [Character Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets) includes supplementaries and explicitly excludes surrogates so a "char" in XML is a Unicode scalar value, and there is a well-formedness constraint for [Character References](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#dt-charref): "Characters referred to using character references must match the production for Char." which is violated by Xalan and XSLTC.

Comment: One way I found to awoid the xalan serializer bug is to use a UTF-16 encoding... LSSerializer.writeToString is also using UTF-16...

Comment: Are you saying that applying the identity transformation with Xalan on this XML document: `<t>&#119964;</t>` produces something else? I can't believe this.

Comment: @Dimitre : yes, this is exactly what Dragisa Krsmanovic has tried, and he made a nice table of the results that you can see in the link. Go on and try it too if you don't believe.

Comment: @Damien, The problem is I don't have Xalan installed. :( Also, I don't see Dragisa using any XSLT transformation. I asked if *the identity transform* has this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I didn't see any answer coming, and other people seem to have the same problem, I looked into it further...

To find the origin of the bug, I used the `serializer` source code from `Xalan 2.7.1`, which is also used in `Xerces`.

`org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.LSSerializerImpl` uses `org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLStream`, which extends `org.apache.xml.serializer.ToStream`.

`ToStream.characters(final char chars[], final int start, final int length)` handles the characters, and does not support unicode characters properly (note: `org.apache.xml.serializer.ToTextSream` (which can be used with a `Transformer`) does a better job in the characters method, but it only handles plain text and ignores all markup; one would think that XML files are text, but for some reason `ToXMLStream` does not extend `ToTextStream`).

`org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl` is also using `org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLStream` (which is returned by `org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializerFactory.getSerializer(Properties format)`), so it suffers from the same bug.

`ToStream` is using `org.apache.xml.serializer.CharInfo` to check if a character should be replaced by a `String`, so the bug could also be fixed there instead of directly in `ToStream`. `CharInfo` is using a propery file, `org.apache.xml.serializer.XMLEntities.properties`, with a list of character entities, so changing this file could also be a way to fix the bug, although so far it is designed just for the special XML characters (`quot`,`amp`,`lt`,`gt`). The only way to make `ToXMLStream` use a different property file than the one in the package would be to add a `org.apache.xml.serializer.XMLEntities.properties` file before in the classpath, which would not be very clean...

With the default JDK (1.6 and 1.7), `TransformerFactory` returns a `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl`, which uses `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLStream`. In `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream`, `characters()` is sometimes calling `processDirty()`, which calls `accumDefaultEscape()`, which could handle unicode characters better, but in practice it does not seem to work (maybe `processDirty` is not called for unicode characters)...

`com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl` is using `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer`, which supports unicode. Strangely enough, `XMLSerialize`r comes from `Xerces`, and yet it is not used by `Xerces` when `xalan` or `xsltc` are on the classpath. This is because `org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDOMImplementationImpl.createLSSerializer` is using `org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.LSSerializerImpl` when it is available instead of `org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMSerializerImpl`. With `serializer.jar` on the classpath, `org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.LSSerializerImpl` is used. Warning: `xalan.jar` and `xsltc.jar` both reference `serializer.jar` in the manifest, so `serializer.jar` ends up on the classpath if it is in the same directory and either `xalan.jar` or `xsltc.jar` is on the classpath ! If only `xercesImpl.jar` and `xml-apis.jar` are on the classpath, `org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMSerializerImpl` is used as the `LSSerializer`, and unicode characters are properly handled.

CONCLUSION AND WORKAROUND: the bug lies in Apache's `org.apache.xml.serializer.ToStream` class (renamed `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream` inside the JDK). A serializer that handles unicode characters properly is `org.apache.xml.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl` (renamed `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl` inside the JDK). However, Apache prefers `ToStream` instead of `DOMSerializerImpl` when it is available, so maybe it behaves better for other things (or maybe it's just a reorganization). On top of that, they went as far as deprecating `DOMSerializerImpl` in `Xerces 2.9.0`. Hence the following workaround, which might have side effects :

- when `Xerces` and Apache's `serializer` are on the classpath, replace "`(doc.getImplementation()).createLSSerializer()`" by "`new org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMSerializerImpl()`"
- when Apache's `serializer` is on the classpath (for instance because of `xalan`) but not `Xerces`, try to replace "`(doc.getImplementation()).createLSSerializer()`" by "new `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl()`" (a fallback is necessary because this class might disappear in the future)

These 2 workarounds produce a warning when compiling.

I don't have a workaround for `XSLT transforms`, but this is beyond the scope of the question. I guess one could do a transform to another DOM document and use `DOMSerializerImpl` to serialize.

Some other workarounds, which might be a better solution for some people :

- use `Saxon` with a `Transformer`
- use XML documents with `UTF-16` encoding

Comment: I created a bug report on jira : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2560

Comment: Christopher Taylor commented on jira: "possible dupe of XALANJ-2419, which has a patch attached. Also referenced in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511474/surrogate-pair-handling-in-xalan-2-7-1 ". Xalan has enjoyed renewed activity lately, so there is hope for an eventual bug fix.

Comment: You got me into the right direction :) I use a library which itself makes use of xalan, where xalan-serializer is not needed. While xalan comes with the dependency to xalan-serializer, dumping that dependency makes my library work, hooray !

Comment: Hm, actually I think it's  the dependency to xercesImpl which needs xml-apis, dumping that dependency makes my library work. Whatever: hooray ! Note: use as less dependencies as possible

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that worked for me.  Code is written in Groovy running on Java 7, which you can easily translate to Java since I've used all Java APIs in the example.  If you pass in a DOM document that has supplementary (plane 1) unicode characters and you will get back out a String which has those characters properly serialized.  For example, if the document has a unicode Script L (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d4c1/index.htm), it will be serialized in the returned String as `&#x1d4c1` instead of `&#55349;&#56513;` (which is what you will get with a Xalan Transformer).

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document
...

def String writeToStringLS( Document doc ) {
  def domImpl = doc.getImplementation()
  def implLS = domImpl.getFeature("LS", "3.0")
  def lsOutput = implLS.createLSOutput()
  lsOutput.encoding = "UTF-8"
  def bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  def out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( bo, "UTF-8") )
  lsOutput.characterStream = out
  def lsWriter = implLS.createLSSerializer()
  def result = lsWriter.write(doc, lsOutput)
  return bo.toString()
}
```