# How to write rootless list in xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to write an xml file using the following format:

```
<root>
    <date> 9:51 AM 10/10/2012 </date>
    <responseTime> 1.20</responseTime>
    <employee>
        <name> Mohammad</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name> Ali</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name> Mostafa</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name> Mahmoud</name>
    </employee>
</root>
```

Can I wrote it using DOM? or should I write it by hand?

(The problem in that the employee node is a sequence without a direct parent node to warp all employee elements without `date` and `responseTime` elements)

Comment: "The problem in that the employee node is a sequence without a parent node" — What is `<root>` if not a parent node?

Comment: Have a sequence with date and responseTime followed by 1 or more instances of employee.  1 or more instances of employee can itself be a complex type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem with doing it with DOM.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, TransformerException
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Element root = document.createElement("root");
    document.appendChild(root);

    Element emp1 = document.createElement("employee");
    Element emp1name = document.createElement("name");
    emp1name.setTextContent("Mohammad");
    emp1.appendChild(emp1name);
    Element emp2 = document.createElement("employee");
    Element emp2name = document.createElement("name");
    emp2name.setTextContent("Ali");
    emp2.appendChild(emp2name);

    root.appendChild(emp1);
    root.appendChild(emp2);

    printDocument(document, System.out);
}
```

**Output:**

```
<root>
    <employee>
        <name>Mohammad</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Ali</name>
    </employee>
</root>
```

You can see the source code for `printDocument` in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325407/357360).

Full source code can be found [here](http://ideone.com/bfTbl).

Comment: The major problem I am talking about is to have this sequence with `responseTime` and `date` elements

Comment: @Muhammad - I don't see the problem with the sequence - check this link, it will show you it works fine: http://ideone.com/bfTbl

Comment: Ohh, yes. But Can we have an XSD for that? I need to generate such output from some DTO java object to have this xml generated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815335/how-to-write-an-xsd-for-a-list-with-no-wrapper-element

Comment: That is a totally different question - this is the 1st time you mentioned an XSD - as far as I know, the answer is yes. You can define an XSD for that.

Comment: How to do so?, please follow my question

Comment: I did this at first, please edit your answer so I can undo-downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write that with DOM (the parent node for "employee" is "root"), however it would be nicer to wrap "employee" nodes with "employees" for example...