# How to write an XSD for a list with no wrapper element

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to have `xsd:complexType` contains `xsd:sequence` and `xsd:element`?

```
<xsd:complexType name="employeesType" mixed="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="employee" type="employeeType"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <!-- ERROR
    <xsd:element name="responseTime" type="responseTimeType"></xsd:element>
     -->
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you show in your example above it is not allowed to have an `<xsd:element />` as a direct child of `<xsd:complexType />` (see [reference at w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/schema/el_complextype.asp)). Considering the example from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814752/how-to-write-rootless-list-in-xml) I think what you want to do can be achieved with a schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="responseTime" type="xsd:decimal" />
            <xsd:element name="employee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

This validates for your example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <date> 9:51 AM 10/10/2012 </date>
    <responseTime> 1.20</responseTime>
    <employee>
        <name> Mohammad</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name> Ali</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name> Mostafa</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name> Mahmoud</name>
    </employee>
</root>
```

You might want to change the type of `<date />` to `xsd:date` though.