# Why does javax.xml.xpath.XPath act differently with a cloned node?

Tags: java

Given the following XML (basic.xml):

```
<rdr>
  <details>
    <detail>
        <name>version</name>
        <value>15.0</value>
    </detail>
    <detail>
        <name>resolution</name>
        <value>1080X1920</value>
    </detail>
  </details>
</rdr>
```

I want to get the name and versions out, so I have the following code.  This isn't very tidy, but I have created this for illustrative purposes, but the code does fully function:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Example {

    private static XPath factoryXpath = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("basic.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(fin);

        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        factoryXpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

        printDetails(document);
    }

    public static void printDetails(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) factoryXpath.evaluate("//detail", node, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        printNameAndValue(nodes.item(0));
        printNameAndValue(nodes.item(1));

    }

    public static void printNameAndValue(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
        System.out.println("Name=" + (String) factoryXpath.evaluate("//name", node, XPathConstants.STRING));
        System.out.println("Value=" + (String) factoryXpath.evaluate("//value", node, XPathConstants.STRING));
    }

}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Name=version
Value=15.0
Name=version
Value=15.0
```

Why does it output the same Name and Value both times?

If I clone the node first, so that printNameAndValue now looks like this:

```
public static void printNameAndValue(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
    Node clonedNode = node.cloneNode(true);
    System.out.println("Name=" + (String) factoryXpath.evaluate("//name", clonedNode, XPathConstants.STRING));
    System.out.println("Value=" + (String) factoryXpath.evaluate("//value", clonedNode, XPathConstants.STRING));
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Name=version
Value=15.0
Name=resolution
Value=1080X1920
```

Why does a cloned node act differently?

I removed the cloned node and reverted to the original example where it doesn't work and added the method described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325407/211560 but with it taking a Node instead of a Document in its attributes.  This prints out the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><detail>
        <name>version</name>
        <value>15.0</value>
    </detail>
Name=version
Value=15.0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><detail>
        <name>resolution</name>
        <value>1080X1920</value>
    </detail>
Name=version
Value=15.0
```

It is clear from this that the node is the one we would expect; but it is applying the XPath to the first node, or maybe to the original document.  I'm OK with cloning a node and using that but I'd really like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath expression `//name` is an *absolute* path (beginning with a `/`), so selects a node set containing all `name` elements in the document to which the context node belongs.  Thus evaluating that expression as a string according to the XPath 1.0 data model will give you the string value of the *first* such node in document order.

The crucial part of that first sentence is "the document to which the context node belongs" - a cloned node is not attached to a document, so the XPath evaluator treats the node itself as the root of a document fragment and evaluates the expression against that fragment (which contains only one `name` element) instead of against the original document (which contains two).

If in `printNameAndValue` you instead used relative XPath expressions

```
public static void printNameAndValue(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
    System.out.println("Name=" + (String) factoryXpath.evaluate("name", node, XPathConstants.STRING));
    System.out.println("Value=" + (String) factoryXpath.evaluate("value", node, XPathConstants.STRING));
}
```

(or `.//name` if the `name` element might be a grandchild or deeper rather than an immediate child) then you should get the output you expect, i.e. the value of the first `name` (respectively `value`) element child of the specified `node`.

Comment: Thank-you.  I assumed that a node would discard the document from which it is part of; but this does explain why.