# Error in opening the webpage in JavaFx web view

Tags: java, webview, javafx, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I am trying to open a webpage in javafx webview . Its throwing a fatal error exception

Error is this-

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6e98299b, pid=4116, tid=4224

JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
   Problematic frame:
   V  [jvm.dll+0xb299b]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
   C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\NetCheck\hs_err_pid4116.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

What is the reason for the above error , I am using the following code.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import javafx.application.Platform;
 import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
 import javafx.scene.Group;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
 import javafx.scene.web.WebView;



public class Browser extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{

  JFXPanel fxpanel;
  WebEngine eng;
  public Browser() {
  initComponents();
  setLayout(null);
  fxpanel=new JFXPanel();
  add(fxpanel);
  fxpanel.setBounds(50,50,700,500);
  setBounds(0,0,1024,768);

 }


 private  void initFx(final JFXPanel fxpanel)

 {
  try
   {
    Group group= new Group();
    Scene scene= new Scene(group);
    fxpanel.setScene(scene);    
    WebView webview = new WebView ();
    group.getChildren().add(webview);
    webview.setMinSize(700,500);
    webview.setMaxSize(700,500); 
    webview.setVisible(true);
    eng= webview.getEngine();
    eng.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    eng.load("http://www.google.com");
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
  Browser b1= new Browser();
  b1.show();

  }

   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)


   {
     Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run()
      {
        initFx(fxpanel);
     }}
       );

  }
```

Comment: post this bug on oracle you may get the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your JDK, you have a very old `1.7.0u10` version (December 2012) and the latest JDK 7 version is `1.7.0u45`.

Be aware, that `WebView` in [JDK 7 contains some minor bugs](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11048688) which are fixed in JDK 8 and are unlikely to be fixed in JDK 7. Some of the bugs I noticed are with font rendering, i.e. Font Awesome and Ace Editor didn't work for me well in JDK 7.

**UPDATE**

You demo is working on JDK `1.7.0u40`. You need to call `initFx` in the fx app thread:

```
  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initFx(fxpanel);
        }
  });
```

Comment: In JDK 8 jdbc:odbc support is not present, what is the alternate

Comment: You demo is working for me, I've updated the sample. I think it should also work at u45.

Comment: Ya its working on some systems this error is related to JVM as i know but i have no solution about it

Comment: Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the code which is not working for 1.7.0u45? If it really doesn't work, it might also be an issue of Swing+FX combination, you could try using JavaFX alone. Here is a browser demo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20135387/1851024.