# Pretty print XML in java 8

Tags: java, xml, dom, pretty-print

I have an XML file stored as a DOM Document and I would like to pretty print it to the console, preferably without using an external library. **I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times on this site, however none of the previous answers have worked for me.** I am using java 8, so perhaps this is where my code differs from previous questions? I have also tried to set the transformer manually using code found from the web, however this just caused a `not found` error.

Here is my code which currently just outputs each xml element on a new line to the left of the console.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class Test {
    public Test(){
        try {
            //java.lang.System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory;
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
            Document original = null;
            try {
                dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                original = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("xml Store - Copy.xml"))));
            } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            //tf.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
            Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(original), xmlOutput);
            java.lang.System.out.println(xmlOutput.getWriter().toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error converting to String", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess that the problem is related to **blank text nodes** (i.e. text nodes with only whitespaces) in the original file. You should try to programmatically remove them just after the parsing, using the following code. If you don't remove them, the `Transformer` is going to preserve them.

```
original.getDocumentElement().normalize();
XPathExpression xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//text()[normalize-space(.) = '']");
NodeList blankTextNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(original, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < blankTextNodes.getLength(); i++) {
     blankTextNodes.item(i).getParentNode().removeChild(blankTextNodes.item(i));
}
```

Answer (score 57):

In reply to Espinosa's comment, here is a solution when "*the original xml is not already (partially) indented or contain new lines*".

**Background**

Excerpt from the article (see *References* below) inspiring this solution:

> *Based on the DOM specification, whitespaces outside the tags are perfectly valid and they are properly preserved. To remove them, we can use XPath’s normalize-space to locate all the whitespace nodes and remove them first.*

**Java Code**

```
public static String toPrettyString(String xml, int indent) {
    try {
        // Turn xml string into a document
        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"))));

        // Remove whitespaces outside tags
        document.normalize();
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//text()[normalize-space()='']",
                                                      document,
                                                      XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
        }

        // Setup pretty print options
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", indent);
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        // Return pretty print xml string
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
        return stringWriter.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**Sample usage**

```
String xml = "<root>" + //
             "\n   "  + //
             "\n<name>Coco Puff</name>" + //
             "\n        <total>10</total>    </root>";

System.out.println(toPrettyString(xml, 4));
```

**Output**

```
<root>
    <name>Coco Puff</name>
    <total>10</total>
</root>
```

**References**

- [Java: Properly Indenting XML String](http://myshittycode.com/2014/02/10/java-properly-indenting-xml-string/) published on *MyShittyCode*
- [Save new XML node to file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33936257/363573)

Comment: This is actually pretty similar to the code which I ended up using :).

Comment: @btrs20 The difference relies in the whitespaces removal.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, simple recursion looking for white space only text nodes, no xpath. Yours code shorter. Nice example of advanced XPath. Thanks.

Comment: If this works perfect. But if you have some exceptions regarding the lack of `indend-number` attribute the solution will be to check the classpath for classes implementing TransformerFactory. I had in classpath the library `net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE` that defined an additional TransformerFactory.

Comment: Removal of the whitespace is important. The transformer doesn't work if your String has whitespace between lines.

Comment: Note that this does not play well with XHTML DOCTYPE declarations (it tries to fetch them); once removed, this solution works very well. Also note that because of other imports I had to use org.w3c.dom.Document and org.w3c.dom.Node explicitly instead of Document and Node, and instead of the ByteArrayInputStream you can use InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(code)); (passing in inputSource to DocumentBuilder.parse()).

Comment: could someone resolve the problem with the intend-number not interpreted? also the XML declaration is on the same line than the root element (don't want to omit it).

Comment: @benez can you please post your problem in a new question?

Comment: @Stephan ehm no. i don't see this to be a different topic. feel free to create your own questions. the intend is surely part of what most developers expect to be a "pretty" print. none of the solutions posted here have solved the intend yet.

Comment: @benez Im sorry, the "intend-number not interpreted" problem is totally unclear. Further comments won't explicit it.

Comment: @Stephan i am using jdk8u162. executing the above code with `transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", indent);` simply does not add any indent to the output of the method. i expect to see spaces at the beginning of any inner xml-tag. seems like this is ignored.

Comment: @benez I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. Please detail it in a new question and feel free to post a link back here in a comment.

Comment: I like this answer except that it adds a line break at the end.

Comment: @Marteng You may try underscore-java library and U.formatXml(xml) method.

Answer (score 6):

This works on Java 8:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String xmlString = "<hello><from>ME</from></hello>";
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
    pretty(document, System.out, 2);
}

private static void pretty(Document document, OutputStream outputStream, int indent) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    if (indent > 0) {
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", Integer.toString(indent));
    }
    Result result = new StreamResult(outputStream);
    Source source = new DOMSource(document);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that also works for me so I guess the problem must be in the way I read the xml file.

Comment: Warning, this solution only works when in the original xml is not already (partially) indented or contain new lines. That is, it will work for "<hello><from>ME</from></hello>" but NOT for "<hello>\n<from>ME</from>\n</hello>"

Comment: To casual readers, here is a solution for @Espinosa's warning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33541820/363573

Answer (score 2):

I've written a [simple class](https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-core/blob/master/src/test/java/com/greenbird/prettyprinter/tools/WhitespaceRemoverTool.java) for for removing whitespace in documents - supports command-line and does not use DOM / XPath.

Edit: Come to think of it, the project also contains a pretty-printer which handles existing whitespace:

```
PrettyPrinter prettyPrinter = PrettyPrinterBuilder.newPrettyPrinter().ignoreWhitespace().build();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) has static method `U.formatXml(string)`. I am the maintainer of the project. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QaB)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String xml = "<root>" + //
             "\n   "  + //
             "\n<name>Coco Puff</name>" + //
             "\n        <total>10</total>    </root>";

        System.out.println(U.formatXml(xml));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<root>
   <name>Coco Puff</name>
   <total>10</total>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like any of the common XML formatting solutions because they all remove more than 1 consecutive new line character (for some reason, removing spaces/tabs and removing new line characters are inseparable...). Here's my solution, which was actually made for XHTML but should do the job with XML as well:

```
public String GenerateTabs(int tabLevel) {
  char[] tabs = new char[tabLevel * 2];
  Arrays.fill(tabs, ' ');

  //Or:
  //char[] tabs = new char[tabLevel];
  //Arrays.fill(tabs, '\t');

  return new String(tabs);
}

public String FormatXHTMLCode(String code) {
  // Split on new lines.
  String[] splitLines = code.split("\\n", 0);

  int tabLevel = 0;

  // Go through each line.
  for (int lineNum = 0; lineNum < splitLines.length; ++lineNum) {
    String currentLine = splitLines[lineNum];

    if (currentLine.trim().isEmpty()) {
      splitLines[lineNum] = "";
    } else if (currentLine.matches(".*<[^/!][^<>]+?(?<!/)>?")) {
      splitLines[lineNum] = GenerateTabs(tabLevel) + splitLines[lineNum];

      ++tabLevel;
    } else if (currentLine.matches(".*</[^<>]+?>")) {
      --tabLevel;

      if (tabLevel < 0) {
        tabLevel = 0;
      }

      splitLines[lineNum] = GenerateTabs(tabLevel) + splitLines[lineNum];
    } else if (currentLine.matches("[^<>]*?/>")) {
      splitLines[lineNum] = GenerateTabs(tabLevel) + splitLines[lineNum];

      --tabLevel;

      if (tabLevel < 0) {
        tabLevel = 0;
      }
    } else {
      splitLines[lineNum] = GenerateTabs(tabLevel) + splitLines[lineNum];
    }
  }

  return String.join("\n", splitLines);
}
```

It makes **one assumption**: that there are no <> characters except for those that comprise the XML/XHTML tags.

Comment: this snippet is incomplete, since the codeGenerator variable cannot be resolved. is the corresponding class written in java? since java method names do have a different naming convention.

Comment: @benez Sorry about that, and thanks for informing me. I didn't realize there was external code being utilized. Try that, I think it will work; can't test it right now.

Answer (score -3):

Create xml file :

```
new FileInputStream("xml Store - Copy.xml") ;// result xml file format incorrect !
```

so that, when parse the content of the given input source as an XML document
and return a new DOM object.

```
Document original = null;
...
original.parse("data.xml");//input source as an XML document
```