# Java: Formatting XML

Tags: java, xml

I have XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>    
<linearlayout layout_height="match_parent" layout_width="match_parent" orientation="vertical">
  <textview layout_height="wrap_content" layout_width="match_parent" text="Hello XML!"/>
  <button layout_height="wrap_content" layout_width="wrap_content" text="Click Me"/>
</linearlayout>
```

and i want each attribute of element be on it's own line like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>    
<linearlayout 
  layout_height="match_parent" 
  layout_width="match_parent" 
  orientation="vertical">
  <textview 
    layout_height="wrap_content" 
    layout_width="match_parent" 
    text="Hello XML!"/>
  <button 
    layout_height="wrap_content" 
    layout_width="wrap_content" 
    text="Click Me"/>
</linearlayout>
```

how can i do this using java ?

Comment: You can find your answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864316/pretty-print-xml-in-java-8/33541820#33541820

Comment: Do you want each attribute on it's own line?

Comment: @aka-one yes each attribute on it's own line

Answer (score 0):

press `cltl+shift+alt+l` in `xml` and select rearrange from the popup which opens.

Comment: i mean using java code not in the xml document

Answer (score 0):

The [JDOM Java library](http://jdom.org/) provides a formatter to pretty print an XML docment. Just read in an XML source then output the reformated contents.

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(new File(...));

XMLOutputter xo = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
String xmlPrettyContent = xo.outputString(doc);
System.out.println(xmlPrettyContent);
```

You can get an instance to the Formatter and tweak the settings to customize the output as needed.