# How to format XML using Pentaho

Tags: xml, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm producing a XML using several steps and, in the end, due to the complexity of the XML (nested inside nested inside nested) I had to use a Text File Output Step and just change the 'Extension' option to '.xml'.

The problem is I'm getting a one line .xml file insted of a well formatted XML;
If I copy-paste that one line into an xmlFormatter online it works perfectly.

Is there any way of reading that one line file as a String and change it into a well shaped XML  file?

Obtained:
[image: obtained XML]

Pretended:
[image: pretended XML]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no real solution (I wouldn't even recommend it) but have you tried feeding the result from your text output back into the XML formatter? I would like to know the solution to this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a **User Defined Java Class** step and write your own code to transform your XML one-liner into a pretty-printed version. Pentaho already comes with various library JARs for XML operations that you can use directly.

Here is how the test transformation I wrote looks like :

[image]

*Generate XML String* writes a single row containing an XML one-liner string in the 'xml' field.

*Format XML* contains the following code under its 'Processor' tab :

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

public static String toPrettyString(String xml) {
    try {
        // Turn xml string into a document
        Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"))));

        // Remove whitespaces outside tags
        document.normalize();
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//text()[normalize-space()='']",
                                                      document,
                                                      XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
        }

        // Setup pretty print options
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        // Return pretty print xml string
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
        return stringWriter.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
 
    // First, get a row from the default input hop
    Object[] r = getRow();
 
    // If the row object is null, we are done processing.
    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }

    // Init output row
    Object[] outputRow = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
 
    // Getting fields
    String xml = get(Fields.In, "xml").getString(r);
    
    // Init error handling  
    boolean rowInError = false;
    String errMsg = "";
    int errCnt = 0;

    // Init Output
    String xml_pretty = "";

    // Put the xml in pretty format
    try{
        xml_pretty = toPrettyString(xml);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        errMsg = ex.getMessage();
        errCnt++;
        rowInError = true;
    }

    // Set the value in the output field
    //
    get(Fields.Out, "result").setValue(outputRow, true);
    get(Fields.Out, "xml_pretty").setValue(outputRow, xml_pretty);

    if ( !rowInError ) {
        // putRow will send the row on to the default output hop.
        //
        putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRow);
    }
    else {
        // putError will send the row on to the error hop.
        //
        get(Fields.Out, "result").setValue(outputRow, false);
        get(Fields.Out, "xml_pretty").setValue(outputRow, "");
        putError(data.outputRowMeta, outputRow, errCnt, errMsg, "", "ERR_0");
    }

    return true;
}
```

The implementation of *toPrettyString(String xml)* is up to you. Here I used the code found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33541820/12564635). You also have to define the output fields (by giving their names and types) under the 'Fields' tab of the step.

The above code was tested using Spoon/PDI Client on Pentaho 8.3.0.10